# Issue with Components Rendering Only When Using React-Navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I have been looking for a solution online for a few days now, and have started a completely new React project to illustrate the issue.

In the original project, I had a few different pages that would render normally, until I added any sort of React Navigation stuff like Routes and Router tags, after which nothing would render. For example, if I made the entry point "HomePage" it would render the component normally. If I made the entry point "App" which had any sort of Navigation-related component, no matter what I tried I couldn't get anything to render, even typing stuff like localhost:3000/home

So I went ahead and followed the steps for React Navigation with a completely fresh project. Now, I am basically getting the same issue of nothing rendering. As far as I can tell, I'm basically following every detail in the documentation.

Here is my recreation of the problem in a relatively bare and empty project.

**Index.js**
[index.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCTQq.png)

**App.js**
[App.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6nHi.png)

**HomeScreen.js**
[this one works fine on its own](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCTQq.png)

The same issue happens. If I replace  with  I see the component just like I should. With  shows nothing.

I probably have seen like 12 issues like this and nothing has worked for me. Thank you for reading.

I can post my package-lock and package files if that would help. Thanks to anyone for any help or ideas. I use to be able to make navigation like this easily, I really have no idea what I'm doing wrong now.

Comment: Apparently, after nine days of playing video games to clear my head from the issue, all I had to was change the way my <Route> tags looked.

Original (did not work):
<Route path="/" element={<HomePage/ >}/>

New (it worked!):
<Route path="/" element={<HomePage><HomePage/>}/>

As far as I can tell, it worked for, this was after I basically reverted back to the most basic react project set-up that I could, with Index.js looking like:

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);